# Why do we have to explicitly append the unit for xshift and yshift?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I prefer using implicit unit when specifying coordinates because I can globally change the unit via `x` and `y` options later.

I try applying this mechanism on `xshift` and `yshift` but it seems they need explicit unit. Why do we have to explicitly mention the unit in this case?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray!50] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
    \begin{scope}[>=stealth,<->]
        \draw (-4,0) -- (4,0);
        \draw (0,-4) -- (0,4);
    \end{scope}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,1)[red]
    %[xshift=1, yshift=2] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
    [xshift=1cm, yshift=2cm] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## With explicit unit

[image]

## Without explicit unit

[image]

Comment: You could use `shift={(1,2)}` or `shift={(1,0)},shift={(0,2)}`.

Comment: `xshift`/`yshift` use the lower level macros `\pgftransformxshift`/`\pgftransformyshift`, which specifically take a dimension as the argument (according to the manual, section 103.2.2).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use `shift={(1,2)}` or `shift={(1,0)},shift={(0,2)}`. Both result in

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray!50] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
    \begin{scope}[>=stealth,<->]
        \draw (-4,0) -- (4,0);
        \draw (0,-4) -- (0,4);
    \end{scope}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,1)[red]
      [shift={(1,2)}] (0,0) rectangle (2,1)
      %[shift={(1,0)},shift={(0,2)}] (0,0) rectangle (2,1)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You could also define new styles:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  my xshift/.style={shift={(#1,0)}},
  my xshift/.value required,
  my yshift/.style={shift={(0,#1)}},
  my yshift/.value required
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray!50] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
    \begin{scope}[>=stealth,<->]
        \draw (-4,0) -- (4,0);
        \draw (0,-4) -- (0,4);
    \end{scope}
    \draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (2,1)
      [my xshift=1, my yshift=2] (0,0) rectangle (2,1)
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: See the comment of Torbjørn (below your question).

Answer (score 6):

You only have to give the unit if you want it to not be the default. But which unit is default depends on the context. In coordinate specifications, it is one of whatever the standard x / y unit is - 10mm by default. In `xshift` and `yshift` it is 1pt.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[gray!50] (-4,-4) grid (4,4);
    \begin{scope}[>=stealth,<->]
        \draw (-4,0) -- (4,0);
        \draw (0,-4) -- (0,4);
    \end{scope}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,1)[red] [xshift=1cm, yshift=2cm] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
    \draw [thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,1)[blue] [xshift=1, yshift=2] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,1)[green] [xshift=1pt, yshift=2pt] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo rectangles]

Comment: How can I change the `shift` unit? `[x=1cm,y=1cm,xshift=1, yshift=2] (0,0) rectangle (2,1);` does not work.

Comment: @SinglePackAbs I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @SinglePackAbs That is, you can't just do that. You'd have to redefine what the keys do altogether so that they don't invoke the lower level macros they do - or so that they don't invoke them in the same way. This is likely to have all kinds of unwanted side-effects.